# Firefox 29 animations flickering

Tags: html, css, animation, animate.css

I'm using [animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) for animations in my webpage. It was working just fine in all browsers but when I updated my firefox browser to **29** yesterday, there was small **fliker** in all animations I've used. I've started searching for solution since then but I got nothing to solve the problem. Is that bug in new version?

Comment: I have FF29 and I don't see a flicker.

Comment: I can't find anything easily but I seem to recall seeing other problems with FF 29 and flickering animations as well, but only in specific use cases. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Ejaz - the animations on the libraries website -http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ - don't flickr. You could try to reproduce it using your relevant code in a JSFiddle and see if you somebody could help you.

Comment: I've tested it on older version of firefox i.e. 25 from another pc. I don't see any flickering there. Animations are not so smooth as other or older versions have.

Comment: I had the same issue with Javascript based svg animations only on retina displays--no fix...

Answer (score 1):

I think this version of Firefox which you have download is corrupted or it doesn't updated successfully. Try to re download or re-install it.